# cakephp 2.1 xls header content type not working in mac safari

Tags: cakephp-2.1

IN my Project excel layout i add

```
     <?php

      header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
      header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
      header ("Pragma: no-cache");
      header ("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");/*.pdf,.xls*/
      header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.xls" );
      header ("Content-Description: Generated Report" );
     ?>
     <?php echo $content_for_layout ?>
```

and in my controller

```
     function export_xls($id=null) { 
        $this->render('export_xls', 'export_xls');
  }
```

and export_xls.ctp keep it blank.

In windows it create report.xls file  but mac os safari browser it download as report.xls.html 
what to do for that i dont understand.i am using cakephp 2.1

please help me to solve this problem.....

Comment: Have you tried [Media View](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)?

Comment: i used that media view but it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to set the correct `mimeType` or leave it away. CakePHP will fill the `mimeType` automatically if it is a known `mimeType` by CakePHP

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be content either in the .ctp or in the export_xls function. You are not actually outputting anything for the file to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers seem OK (though I think `Content-type`should be `Content-Type`), but try using Cake's built in response classes. Works for me for XLS files. In your controller:

```
$this->response->file($path,array('download' => true, 'name' => 'Report.xls'));
return $this->response;
```